# Check auth with JWT (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I want to protect my routes by adding a middleware 'checkAuth'.
This middleware checks the validity of a jwt token.
I'm using Express router.

But I don't understand how to do that.

My checkAuth middleware :

```js
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

    try {
        jwt.verify(token)
        console.log("ok")
    }catch (e) {
        res.status(403)
    }

    next();
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: `console.log(e)` in your catch what do you get?

Comment: console.log(e) gives me " Unexpected token  in JSON at position 17"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using  [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), you are missing the "secret" string.

According the documentation that's how you should do.

1. when creating token:

   ```
   var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
   var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
   ```

   You could also pass expiration time:

   ```
   jwt.sign({
     data: 'foobar'
   }, 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 });
   ```
2. for validating:

   There a couple of ways you could do it.
   But you should need the same secret string to validate that you used for signing in.
   Also you need to assign a variable to jwt.verify or call it with a callback in order to access the decoded data, such as user Id and so on.

   ```
   // verify a token symmetric - synchronous
   var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh');
   console.log(decoded.foo) // bar

   // verify a token symmetric
   jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
     console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
   });

   // invalid token - synchronous
   try {
     var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'wrong-secret');
   } catch(err) {
     // err
   }

   // invalid token
   jwt.verify(token, 'wrong-secret', function(err, decoded) {
     // err
     // decoded undefined
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function called "verifyToken"

I suggest to promisfy it. So you can use it in an `async` function in combination with `await`

```
function verifyToken(token){
  return new Promise((res, err) => {
    jwt.verify(token, "secret key", (err) => {
      if (err) rej(err)
      res(true)
    })
  })
}
```

Its promise based. Now you just pass your token to the function it resolves to either true or false:

```
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    try {
        await verifyToken(token);
        console.log("ok")
    }catch (e) {
        res.status(403)
    }

    next();
}
```

Comment: This worked too, thanks !